# Avoid Cell specification when moving across for loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use step functions to describe a curve. This is mainly due to other methods not being as precise as this one, in which the data points are connected by a linear relationship. 
I have a table of x-values. Each x-value is taken, and compared to a second table until the following condition is met:

Value2>Value1

Once that is achieved, the second table is used to construct a linear relationship, with which I can accurately calculate the first values actual result, the y-value (assuming y = f(x) ), which is introduced to a last table.

This process has to be repeated then exactly the same way, however the table from which the first value is taken and the table from below which contains the results shifts to the right for every table iteration.

The code I used is as follows:

```
Sub alpha()

    Dim a As Integer
    a = 0
Begin_Count:
    a = a + 1


    Dim l As Integer
    For l = 1 To 13

       'Check the first value
        Val1 = Range(Chr(a + 66) & (l + 269))

        'Check the numbers to compare range
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To 12:
            Val2 = Range(Chr(67) & (i + 284))
            If Val2 > Val1 = True Then

                'Calculate Cl
                dy = (Range("D" & (i + 284)) - Range("D" & (i + 283)))
                dx = (Range("C" & (i + 284)) - Range("C" & (i + 283)))
                x = (Val1 - Range("C" & (i + 283)))
                y = Range("D" & (i + 283))

                Cl = ((dy / dx) * x) + y

                'Insert Cl
                Range(Chr(a + 66) & (l + 299)).Value = Cl

                Exit For
            End If


        Next


    Next
    If a < 101 = True Then
        GoTo Begin_Count
    End If

End Sub
```

This code runs until it reaches the point in which the cells from Excel are labeled "AA","AB",etc., at which the code gives an error.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Range(Chr(a + 66) & (l + 299)).Value = Cl
```

use

```
Cells(l+299, a).Value = Cl
```

In general it's easier to use `Cells()` with two numeric arguments than to try to create an address string to pass to `Range()`, particularly if you're working on a single cell.

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple quick things...

Always use `Option Explicit` in your code modules. It forces you to declare your variables and helps avoid crossing up value types.

Always create a worksheet object, so you can "guarantee" which worksheet your code refers. It makes it more clear, especially when you're involving multiple worksheets (maybe not now, but later).

Finally, refer to the values in your table using the `Cells(rowindex,columnindex)` format. This way you can index rows and columns numerically.

```
Option Explicit

sub alpha()
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Dim a as Integer
    Dim lrow as Integer, lcol as Integer
    Dim irow as Integer, icol as Integer
    Dim 

    Set ws = Activesheet
    a = 0

    Val1 = ws.Cells(lrow, lcol).value
end sub
```

Comment: I get an error here when using option explicit, since it tells me that val1 is not defined. But am I not defining it right there? Other than that, the tips are very useful, thanks!